# Chunk file into multiple streams in scala

Tags: scala, file, bufferedreader

I have a use case in my program where I need to take a file, split them equally N times and upload them remotely.

I'd like a function that takes, say a `File` and output a list of `BufferedReader`. To which I can just distribute them and send them to another function which uses some API to store them.

I've seen examples where authors utilize the `.lines()` method of a `BufferedReader`:

```
def splitFile: List[Stream] = {
    val temp = "Test mocked file contents\nTest"
    val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(lolz.getBytes)
    val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))

    // Chunk the file into two sort-of equal parts.
    // Stream 1
    val test = br.lines().skip(1).limit(1)

    // Stream 2
    val test2 = br.lines().skip(2).limit(1)
    List(test, test2)
}
```

I suppose that the above example works, it's not beautiful but it works.

My questions:

- Is there a way to split a `BufferedReader` into multiple list of streams?
- I don't control the format of the `File`, so the file contents could potentially be a single line long. Wouldn't that just mean that `.lines()` just load all that into a `Stream` of one element?

Comment: Do you need to output 2 readers? Can you read the file, and then split the data in two? 2 readers gets into all sorts of weird interlocking state that you probably don't want anyway.

Comment: I'm flexible, what would you suggest?

Comment: When you say split them equally, do you mean like the even lines go in one stream and the odd lines in another (for N=2), or the first and second half get separate streams?

Comment: @ErikLilja; Does the "above example" really work? I'm unable to retrieve the complete input.

Comment: @jwvh Huh, you're right. The example above does not seem to work since the buffered reader is well, buffered and has executed already.

It has nothing to do with the odd or even lines, I just want to evenly distribute the file contents over multiple files and be able to re-create them later.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to read the file once, and then split it up. You're not really losing anything either, since the file read is a serial operation anyway. From there, just devise a scheme to slice up the list. In this case, I group everything based on its index modulo the number of desired output lists, then pull out the lists. If there are fewer lines than you ask for, it will just place each line in a separate `List`.

```
val lines: List[String] = br.lines
val outputListQuantity: Int = 2
val data: List[List[String]] = lines.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._2 % outputListQuantity}.
                                        values.map(_.map(_._1)).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind reading the whole stream into memory, it's easy enough (assuming, that file contains text - since you are talking about `Reader`s, but it would be the same idea with binary):

```
 Source.fromFile("filename")
   .mkString
   .getBytes
   .grouped(chunkSize)
   .map { chunk => new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(chunk)) }
```

But that seems to sorta defeat the purpose: if the file is small enough to be loaded into memory entirely, why bother splitting it to begin with?
So, a more practical solution is a little bit more involved:

```
  def splitFile(
    input: InputStream, 
    chunkSize: Int
  ): Iterator[InputStream] = new AbstractIterator[InputStream] {
     var hasNext = true
     def next = {
       val buffer = new Array[Byte](chunkSize)
       val bytes = input.read(buffer)
       hasNext = bytes == chunkSize
       new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, 0, bytes max 0)
     }
  }
```